# NotWritablePropertyException error in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

**caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'isTestCtx' of bean class [com.uz.SysConfig]: Bean property 'isTestCtx' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?**

the model code:

```
public class SysConfig {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Value("${isTestCtx}")
    private boolean isTestCtx;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        log.info(" isTestCtx: {}", isTestCtx);
    }
}
```

with the lombok produced code, i can see

```
 public boolean isTestCtx() {
        return this.isTestCtx;
    }

    public void setTestCtx(boolean isTestCtx) {
        this.isTestCtx = isTestCtx;
    }
```

everything goes well. I don't know why this error occurs.
Anyone can help ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653301/error-setting-property-values-nested-exception-is-org-springframework-beans-not)

Comment: Well what's the purpose of @ Getter and @ Setter, rest of the code seems fine. You don't even need getters and setters. Also how are you defining the spring beans here.

Comment: @Himanshu Bhardwaj  @ Setter and @ Getter are lombok's annotation

Comment: Nice! got to know something knew 'Lombok'

Answer (score 1):

The Lombok generated code seems wrong (apparently it's in their fine print at the bottom of this [page](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html), although it only mentions the getter).

For a `boolean` property `isTextCtx`, the expected getter and setters according to the JavaBeans spec would have to be:

```
public boolean isIsTestCtx() {
    return this.isTestCtx;
}

public void setIsTestCtx(boolean isTestCtx) {
    this.isTestCtx = isTestCtx;
}
```

Renaming your property to `testCtx` should resolve the problem though.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Value("${isTestCtx}")
private boolean testCtx;
```

Comment: @Sam It's in no way a duplicate. The one you indicate as the original is not dealing with getters and setters that are generated by Lombok. And, your answer just told OP to change the name of the setter, which he can't since it's being auto-generated.

Comment: I give up. You clearly have not heard of project Lombok. And, BTW, your answer did not precede mine by 10-15 seconds, it was posted at exactly the same time.

Comment: OK, once again: 1) the setters are (wrongly) auto-generated by project Lombok, they are not implemented by OP so can also not be corrected by OP as you suggest in your answer; 2) Spring does not use the EL expression in the `@Value` annotation to infer the name of the setter method. It uses the name of the bean property itself.

Comment: Robby thank you...update the answer with this...nice explanation